# Nginx with dnsmasq 'could not be resolved (5: Operation refused)'

Tags: nginx, docker, dnsmasq, container

I'm trying to set up a django site using docker, nginx and uwsgi:
I have a nginx docker container working as a reverse proxy (called ceca-nginx-proxy) and another nginx (ceca-nginx) container that communicates with an uwsgi container (ceca-uwsgi), I can connect using curl (with `curl --resolve http://test.ceca.com http://172.17.0.7`) to the ceca-nginx container and I get the django site running in the ceca-uwsgi container, the problem is when I want to get the site via ceca-nginx-proxy: I'm getting this error in my ceca-nginx-proxy error log:

> ceca-nginx could not be resolved (5: Operation refused), client: 172.17.0.1, server: *.ceca.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "172.17.0.8"

- 172.17.0.1 is the docker ip assigned
- *.ceca.com is the server_name defined in the ceca-nginx-proxy's nginx config
- 172.17.0.8 is the ceca-nginx-proxy ip
- The server block of ceca-nginx-proxy reverse proxy is:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name *.ceca.com;
      error_log   /tmp/proxy_error_nginx.log warn;
      access_log  /tmp/proxy_access_nginx.log;

      location / {
          set $example ceca-nginx;
          resolver 127.0.0.1;
          proxy_pass http://$example;
      }
  }
  ```

  And I'm running dnsmasq in the same machine to resolve hostnames in /etc/hosts (hostnames from docker linked containers) like this:

  ```
  dnsmasq -q -8 /tmp/dnsmasq.log --port 53 -R -u root
  ```

  For what I see in dnsmasq.log, the hostname is resolving ok [1] but nginx is complaining and returning a "502 Bad Gateway" page.
  If anyone can help me with this, I'll be eternally grateful and buy lots of beer and fernet if we met.

  ```
  [1]

  Jun  6 21:39:47 dnsmasq[321]: query[A] ceca-nginx from 127.0.0.1
  Jun  6 21:39:48 dnsmasq[321]: /etc/hosts ceca-nginx is 172.17.0.7
  Jun  6 21:39:48 dnsmasq[321]: query[AAAA] ceca-nginx from 127.0.0.1
  ```

Comment: Well, the solution was to use `resolve 127.0.0.1;` but without `dnsmasq` running and `nginx 1.10`... I'm not sure why, but now it is working